# Does it make sense to use _attribute__ ((nothrow)) inside extern C?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, attributes, extern-c

I have some C code being called from C++.
The header resembles the following:

```
#ifndef CLibH
#define CLibH

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//C API
void foo(void);
// ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Since I'm already using `extern C`,
is there any benefit to adding the `nothrow` compiler attribute?

```
#ifndef CLibH
#define CLibH

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//C API
void foo(void) __attribute__((nothrow));
// ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Does `extern C` make this redundant?
Are there still advantages to applying it under these circumstances?

Comment: @iharob: It could call into external Fortran code, which could throw.

Comment: @iharob Exactly.  So the compiler should optimize just the same with or without the attribute?  I wasn't sure if there were some subtleties with libraries, or if C code could call back into C++, etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB So "extern C" does not guarantee "no throw".  A function can still throw if it is wrapped in "extern C".  That makes sense.

Comment: `extern "C"` can call straight into C++ code marked as `extern "C"`.  So the questions becomes can exceptions propagate out of a C++ function marked as `extern "C"`?

Comment: I feel very stupid. I myself wrote a c++ plugin system which of course used c to construct classes. Contructors can throw and I used `new` of course, so it's not redundant at ll. In fact you can externalize any c++ function and use *stl*, the `new` operator (*which does throw exceptions*). The only thing `extern "C"` does is prevent name mangling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. From gcc documentation:

> For example, most functions in the standard C library can be
>   guaranteed not to throw an exception with the notable exceptions of
>   qsort and bsearch that take function pointer arguments.